# Ubuntu Detects 2 monitors when I only have one

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

Ubuntu Detects 2 monitors when I only have 1. This causes an issue when booting up because it's detecting 2 monitors and by default it is mirroring the display; which is causing a distorted picture since it's trying to create a mirror image on 1 display. xrandr output.... The VGA1 is the phantom monitor and I need to remove it so it boots to LVDS1 and NOT mirrored.

Any suggestions on how to permanently remove VGA1?

```
:~$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
1024x768 60.0
800x600 60.3 56.2
848x480 60.0
640x480 59.9
LVDS1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
1920x1080 59.6*+
1680x1050 60.0 59.9
1600x1024 60.2
1400x1050 60.0
1280x1024 60.0
1440x900 59.9
1280x960 60.0
1360x768 59.8 60.0
1152x864 60.0
1024x768 60.0
800x600 60.3 56.2
640x480 59.9
```

Comment: `xrandr --output VGA1 --off` should disable VGA1, `xrandr --output VGA1 --auto` should bring it back. If this solved the problem leave a comment and I'll add an answer. Otherwise issue `lspci | grep -i vga` and post the results.

Comment: Looks like it didn't work

Comment: root@# lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

Comment: My computer is a Gateway ZX6800 touch-screen

Comment: This is the fix:
Edit /etc/default/grub, adding "video=VGA-1:d" between the quotes in the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX line

sudo update-grub

FIXED!
Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: it works for me. i have in my notebook DELL L502X screen LVDS1, then external screen in displayport HDMI1 and finally unknown display VGA-1-2. whatever i have change in /etc/default/grub the line in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX "video=VGA-1:d" and in monitor settings disappear the unknown display. thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with certain motherboards that have an HDMI and a Display Port. I figured out that either my Gateway ZX6800 Touch-Screen is using a certain Laptop motherboard with the on-board Intel HD chipset that supports this or it is seeing the IR Blaster or TV Tuner and driving it as a monitor.

Either way the fix is: 
Edit /etc/default/grub 
add "video=VGA-1:d" between the quotes in the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX line
update-grub

***Look in /sys/class/drm for a list of your computers outputs.Mine was labelled as "card0-VGA-1". Just remove the "card0-" and that's the name of the output in question.***

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue with an integrated Intel HD graphics unit (JUSTOP G-PC iA8 Desktop) and missing mouse pointer.

I thought I would add additional help..

to get the correct video to disable...

```
ls /sys/class/drm
```

note the name that is similar to the output from

```
xrandr -q
```

e.g. my connected (but non existent extra screen was DSI1 in xrandr but card0-DSI-1 in /sys/class/drm)

based on this information the correct kernal data from /sys/class/drm I was then able to correct the syntax in my...

```
/etc/default/grub
```

file to read

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=DSI-1:d"
```

then ran

```
sudo update-grub
```

and rebooted, now only one HDMI screen connected and working mouse. Hope this helps other people.

Comment: Mine was named eDP-1, it worked tx

Answer (score 2):

Based on the solution of Matthew Aylard above, I checked the connected cards:

```
ls /sys/class/drm
```

The output was like this:

```
card0  card0-DP-1  card0-HDMI-A-1  card0-LVDS-1  card0-VGA-1  card1  card1-VGA-2  renderD128  renderD129  ttm  version
```

Then I checked

```
xrandr -q
```

Turned out in my case, `VGA-1-2` was wrongly detected as my second screen which caused the this issue. So, I edited grub configuration file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

And added two lines to disable both `VGA-1` and `VGA-2`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=VGA-1:d"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=VGA-2:d"
```

Finally, updated grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And after reboot, the second "unknown" display which has been there for years, was gone!

Answer (score 1):

I have what seems to be a similar problem on pop!_OS (based on Ubuntu 19.10),

Adding "video=VGA-1:d" or "video=VGA-1-2:d" (which what seemed to be connected in the xrandr command) didn't solve it.

I used the Fn+(select screen) function in the keyboard to chose the built in only display. And that solved the issue.

Hope this helps someone.