# Two monitors when only having one in 13.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor, 13.10

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 64bit, and it says that I have 2 monitors, when I actually only have one

[image]

I have a Dell XPS 15 with Nvidia graphics card if that helps in anyway

Comment: Your Laptop Have Or Desktop have DVI port ? or HDMI port ? if so it will be there its not a issue

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am not an expert but I had the same problem. I have finally find the solution on this forum ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283018/ubuntu-detects-2-monitors-when-i-only-have-one)).

First, enter `xrandr` in your terminal. You will see that there are several outputs which are connected. The `LVDS1` is your laptop's screen.
Normally, there is another outpout called `VGA-1` or`VGA-2` which is also connected. You have to note the name of this output.

Then, edit your grub with `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and add `video=VGA-1:d` (VGA-1 is the name of the wrong output) in the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line (you must have something like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=VGA-1:d"`).

- If your output is called like `VGA-1-1`, set `video=VGA-1:d` (setting `video=VGA-1-1:d` won't work).
- If your output is called like `VGA-1-2`, set `video=VGA-2:d` (setting `video=VGA-1-2:d` or `video=VGA-1:d` does not seem to work, although one may still try them out separately to be certain).

Then update your grub with `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: Thanks that worked great :D just changed it to 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=VGA-2:d"', but the weird thing is my laptop doesn't even have VGA :/

Comment: Just a minor correction, it should read `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=VGA-1:d"` (there is an equal sign after `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`)

Comment: I have LVDS1 and LVDS1-1, but your solution sis not work for me ...

Answer (score 1):

See my suggestion in [Mouse cursor flickering with ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397002/mouse-cursor-flickering-with-ubuntu-13-10/526212#526212). Installing Bumblebee got rid of the unwanted display and flickering mouse cursor. xrandr -q also displayed only the correct displays whereas before installing BB, it showed the built-in display as well as an extra VGA-1-1 as being connected.