# Unknown display besides laptop Built-in display. Old question but with no answers

Tags: 13.10, multiple-monitors, display

After my update from 12.04 to 13.10 my display configuration started showing an extra unknown monitor, even though I have nothing connected.

[image]

**lscpi:**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)
```

**xrandr**

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+   60.1  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
  1024x768 (0x43)   65.0MHz
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0x44)   40.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  800x600 (0x45)   36.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock   35.2KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock   56.2Hz
```

This problem seems to had been previously asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340691/ubuntu-13-04-using-vgaswitcheroo-breaks-monitor-configuration) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344195/dual-display-was-working-now-i-have-an-unknown-monitor-even-when-it-is-unplug).

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have finally found a working solution in these two questions:
[one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362081/two-monitors-when-only-having-one-in-13-10),
[two](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344195/dual-display-was-working-now-i-have-an-unknown-monitor-even-when-it-is-unplug)

Basically one needs to edit `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and replace

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

by

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=VGA-2:d"
```

where `VGA-2` is the name of the incorrectly connected display shown by `xrandr`.

Run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot

Comment: Same NVIDIA issue. :( For me, it's named `VGA-1-2`. 

Above solution didn't work out of the box due to uncertain reason, so here is what additional things I performed to disable that 'Unknown Display' in Ubuntu GNOME 14.04. 

Removed entries respected to`VGA-1-2` from config file `~/.config/monitors.xml` and executed below command to disable all VGA as I don't use any VGA.
`echo xrandr --output vga --off >> ~/.xinitrc` and finally `sudo reboot` :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this happened with me on my fresh ubuntu 13.10 install, no idea why, I disable it and it works fine. it pops back up when connecting a secondary monitor to my laptop but just disable it again. I think its a display driver issue