# How can I get rid of unknown display?

Tags: 13.04, display

I was messing with the display options, and seriously messed something up. Now my display looks like this:

[image]

I don't see any obvious solution in the display settings. How can I fix this? What additional information should I provide?

**Edit:**

After I run `xrandr` I get this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2390 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-2 connected 1024x768+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
  1024x768 (0x43)   65.0MHz
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0x44)   40.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  800x600 (0x45)   36.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock   35.2KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock   56.2Hz
```

But I still don't know what to get rid off. I think HDMI1 part is the problem because that's what I was messing with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a known bug for Intel Baytrail graphic, also for a nVidia GeForce GT 630M [10de:0de9] graphic card.

If you're using the nVidia graphic card, the solution is easy, just install the proprietary driver from the "Additional Drivers"

Another workaround is to edit your "/etc/default/grub" file, change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

into:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=VGA-2:d"
```

(Since the bogus unknown display is connected to VGA2 in your case)

After that, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot

Reference:

- [An "Unknown" display appears with no external display connected on 12.04.5](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-trusty/+bug/1355562)
- [[Dell Inspiron 3531] "Unknown" display found in display utility [8086:0f31]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1393651)
- [Unknown display besides laptop Built-in display. Old question but with no answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398903/unknown-display-besides-laptop-built-in-display-old-question-but-with-no-answer)

Comment: I used the second approach and it fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and have NVIDIA GeForce 410M. Updating the driver by **NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-390 (proprietary, tested)** from *Software & Updates > Additional Drivers* solved the issue. **But** then when I played videos, I had only the sound; it's all black! I gave up the driver update and used the second approach.

Answer (score 2):

Updating your drivers fixes it.
`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` (selects recommended drivers for you)

In my case it was Nvidia.
You can also go into `Additional Drivers` and select a propriety driver yourself.
After updating, it changed to "(propriety, tested)" itself.

Don't forget to restart.