# Unknown display 14.04.02 LTS

Tags: display, resolution

So as the install of Ubuntu i cant change the resolution in settings. I tried to change it using the terminal but still didn't help. So how to solve this problem ? I'm using the recommended drivers.Clicking detect displays doesn't do anything. I want to get the resolution to 1440x900 but now it just stays on 1024x768.

Comment: It sounds like you have two display, one is the "Unknown", another is your desktop, right? If answer is yes, please check this article:[how-can-i-get-rid-of-unknown-display](http://askubuntu.com/questions/583639/how-can-i-get-rid-of-unknown-display/584483#584483)

Answer (score 0):

Try `arandr`. Always works pretty well for me. [see here](http://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/)