# unknown monitor

Tags: monitor

I hope to find a way to solve a problem about the displays: I have only the built-in display, and nothing else attached, but, in the settings,the system finds also another display, which is unknown. Can anyone tell me how to remove it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
I've just found my solution after a little research:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/362081/two-monitors-when-only-having-one-in-13-10

Answer (score 0):

If you have NVIDIA graphics you might need BumbleBee - check here http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/8-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html

You're looking for "4. Enable the discrete card on systems with Hybrid graphics"