# How can I fix this Workspace glitch?

Tags: unity, workspaces

When I have Workspaces enabled (just 2 x 2)
[image: Enabled]
It shows this:
[image: Cloned screenshot]
It even clones screenshots. 
When disabled, there is still this:
[image: disabled]
And I have to move the window whenever I open a new one from the left screen to the right. I can't actually view the sceen on the left, other than this.
Is there a way to work around this, or a setting I can change?
[image: display setings]

Comment: I seems to think that you have dual screen... Could you add a screenshot of your displays settings pane.

Comment: So disable the blue screen by clicking and turning it off.

Comment: It gives a Blue screen with 'Invalid Format' Written.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/365017/186134 or enable the mirror displays option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in comments:

The computer believed there was a second screen that didn't actually exist.

You can either set them to mirror or disable one of them, and it should be okay.