# Fresh Ubuntu installation showing two displays but I only have one

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 17.04

I've just installed Ubuntu 17.04 and it is detecting two displays but I only have one. it's an unpleasant experience because the display that I don't have is considered as primary display so things like "Plank" appear on that display (which I don't have)

#### Things I've already tried

The first thing I tried is, I hopped over the display section in the settings app and tried to turn the built in display **off**. setting gets applied for 2 minutes and then resets itself to the initial settings.

[Two monitors when only having one in 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362081/two-monitors-when-only-having-one-in-13-10)

The situation in above question is same. but the solution is above question does not work for me.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 720, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected 1280x720+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 332mm x 187mm
   1280x720      59.86*+
   896x672       60.01

   960x600       60.00

   832x624       74.55

   960x540       59.99

   800x600       75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25

   840x525       74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88

   800x512       60.17

   700x525       74.76    70.06    59.98

   640x512       75.02    60.02

   720x450       59.89

   640x480       60.00    75.00    72.81    75.00    59.94

   720x400       70.08

   680x384       59.80    59.96

   576x432       75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06

   512x384       75.03    70.07    60.00

   416x312       74.66

   400x300       72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34

   320x240       72.81    75.00    60.05

DP-1 connected primary 1280x720+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 332mm x 187mm
   1280x720      59.86*+
   832x624       74.55

   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32

   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94

   720x400       70.08
```

Relevant parts of `/etc/default/grub` (IMO, tell me if I need to write full grub file)

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

The problem in above output is that `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` this line doesn't have any content to edit.

[image: Screenshot]

Even a little push in the right direction is appreciated