Display problem with installation on Mac Book Pro; two displays LVDS-1 and LVDS-2
Ubuntu 23.1 installed correctly in a MacBook Pro (2009) but I only get to display a portion of the desktop with no access to any icon. I was able to start a command line window and by using xrandr I was able to see that LVDS-1 and LVDS-2 displays are active. The physical screen is assigned to LVDS-2 while LVDS-1 sits to the left of LVDS-2 as virtual space. Using xrandr, I tried disconnecting LVDS-1 and setting LVDS-2 as the only active monitor but the system did not take these changes. How do I solve this problem?

This solution worked for my Macbook 2010: https://askubuntu.com/questions/283018/ubuntu-detects-2-monitors-when-i-only-have-one
